# wtStrategy requires a secret or key in Node.js app with Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to set up a Node.js application with Docker and Docker Compose. The application uses Passport.js for authentication, and I'm getting an error when I try to start the application in a Docker container. The error message is TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a secret or key.

Here's the relevant part of my passport.middleware.js setup:

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import passport from 'passport';
import { Strategy as JwtStrategy, ExtractJwt } from 'passport-jwt';
import { Strategy as AppleStrategy } from 'passport-apple';
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth20';

import User from '../models/user.js';
import {
  appleAuthCallback,
  googleAuthCallback,
} from '../routes/auth/auth.controller.js';

// Secret keys
const SECRET_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
// Apple auth secret keys
const APPLE_CLIENT_ID = process.env.APPLE_CLIENT_ID;
const APPLE_TEAM_ID = process.env.APPLE_TEAM_ID;
const APPLE_CALLBACK_URL = process.env.APPLE_CALLBACK_URL;
const APPLE_KEY_ID = process.env.APPLE_KEY_ID;
const APPLE_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = process.env.APPLE_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH;
// Google auth secret keys
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET;
const GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL = process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL;

var opts = {
  jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
  secretOrKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET; // replace with your actual secret or key
}


passport.use(
  new JwtStrategy(opts, async (jwtPayload, done) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findById(jwtPayload.sub);
      if (user) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return done(error, false);
    }
  })
);
```

And here's my Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mongo_db:/data/db

  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
      MONGODB_URL: mongodb+srv://mohamadnashaat:llqLGMSIvXaNIk0v@cluster-gamma-cities.7m4w0eq.mongodb.net/
      DB_NAME: thebest_db
      NAME: 'thebest'
      JWT_SECRET: '' //   didnt share it 
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

volumes:
  mongo_db: {}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:slim
WORKDIR /Gamma-studio-main
COPY . .
RUN npm ci
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

.dockerignore

.

```
/node_models
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
docker-compose.yml
```

.env

```
`PORT=3000
MONGO_URL=""
SECRET_KEY=""
#Apple auth
APPLE_CLIENT_ID=""
APPLE_TEAM_ID=""
APPLE_CALLBACK_URL="http://localhost:3000/auth/apple/callback"
APPLE_KEY_ID=""
APPLE_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH=""
#Google auth keys
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=""
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=""
GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL=""
AUTH_REDIRECT_URL=""
AUTH_FAILURE_REDIRECT_URL="/"
```

error massage

`gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      | /Gamma-studio-main/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:45 gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      |         throw new TypeError('JwtStrategy requires a secret or key'); gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      |               ^ gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      |  gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      | TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a secret or key gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      |     at new JwtStrategy (/Gamma-studio-main/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:45:15) gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      |     at file:///Gamma-studio-main/src/middlewares/passport.middleware.js:32:3 gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      |     at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:192:25) gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      |     at async DefaultModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:24) gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      |     at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:40:7) gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      |     at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:66:12) gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      |  gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      | Node.js v20.4.0 gamma-cities-api-main-api-1      |  gamma-cities-api-main-api-1 exited with code`

I tried to set up a Node.js application with Docker and Docker Compose. The application uses Passport.js for authentication, specifically the JwtStrategy. I've set up the JwtStrategy in my Passport.js configuration and provided a secret key through an environment variable (JWT_SECRET). I've also included this environment variable in my Docker Compose file for the api service.

What were I expecting?

I was expecting the application to start successfully in a Docker container. I thought that by providing the JWT_SECRET environment variable in my Docker Compose file, the JwtStrategy would be able to use this secret key and not throw any errors.

However, when I try to start the application in a Docker container, I get an error message saying TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a secret or key. This suggests that the JwtStrategy is not receiving the secret key as expected.

I'm not sure why this is happening, as I believe I've set up everything correctly. I'm looking for help to understand what I might be doing wrong and how I can fix this problem